# Почему не сохраняется вставленное значение через innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

Почему не сохраняется вставленное значение через `innerHTML`?
Когда дебажу код, то после выполнения метода `sorting()` в классе, через `innerHTML` вставляются нужные объекты, а после страница как бы обновляться и возвращается прежнее значение, а не вставленное в HTML коде.

```
class GenerationView {
constructor(options) {
    this._el = options.element;
    this.g1 = this._el.querySelector('.fst');
    this.g2 = this._el.querySelector('.snd');
    this.g3 = this._el.querySelector('.trd');
    this.g4 = this._el.querySelector('.fth');
    this.btn = options.btn;

    this.btn.addEventListener('click', this.sorting.bind(this));
    }


sorting() {
    let type = event.target.getAttribute('data-type');

    if (type === 'new') {
        let new_g = this.g4.innerHTML + this.g3.innerHTML + this.g2.innerHTML + this.g1.innerHTML;
        this._el.innerHTML = new_g;

    }

    if (type === 'old') {
        let old_g = this.g1.innerHTML + this.g2.innerHTML + this.g3.innerHTML + this.g4.innerHTML;
        this._el.innerHTML = old_g;
    }

}
}

let generation = new GenerationView({
  element: document.querySelector('.all_generations'),
  btn: document.querySelector('.sorting'),
});
```

Comment: "как бы обновляться" или обновляется? `this._el = old_g;` - это что делает? Зачем `return`?

Comment: простите за не корректность в коде, return убрал.

Comment: По поводу обновления: при соблюдении условия (type === 'new'), вставляется переменная new_g в this._el (это показывает debbager, когда ставлю его после строки this._el.innerHTML = old_g;) но потом код продолжает выполнятся и в значение this._el возвращается изначальное значение. Не могу понять, как выполняется код после выполнения метода... @Igor

Comment: Посмотрите ответ. Кнопка находится внутри формы? По клику происходит отправка формы и перезагрузка страницы.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь. Дело было не  в JS, а в HTML. В силу своей неопытности повесил обработчик на тег <a href= " "></a> . И так как ссылка пустая, страница просто обновлялась, возвращая изначальное значение.

Answer (score 1):

Кнопка находится внутри формы? По клику происходит отправка формы и перезагрузка страницы.

Возвращайте `false` из обработчика, чтобы этого избежать.

```
sorting() {
    let type = event.target.getAttribute('data-type');

    if (type === 'new') {
        let new_g = this.g4.innerHTML + this.g3.innerHTML + this.g2.innerHTML + this.g1.innerHTML;
        this._el.innerHTML = new_g;
    }

    if (type === 'old') {
        let old_g = this.g1.innerHTML + this.g2.innerHTML + this.g3.innerHTML + this.g4.innerHTML;
        this._el.innerHTML = old_g;
    }

    return false; // !!!
}
```